# Create MS Project XML file in C#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, ms-project

I'd like to create projects and tasks in XML format to MS Project. I've got the schema, and generated the classes from that(Project, Task, Resources, etc.), I can serialize it, but I'dont know the way what properties I need. I tried it manually, but it didnt work. MS Project hasn't shown my tasks. I need only very simple tasks, with start and end date.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Project XML schema is quite complex and awkward to use, particularly if your requirements are simple. You may find it helpful to look at using [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net). This provides a standard API which can read and write various Project related file formats, including MSPDI - the Micrsoft Project XML format. A sample file included in the distribution (MpxjCreate) illustrates the basic attributes you need to populate in order to create tasks, resources and resource assignments. The sample is written in Java but the library ships with a .Net version, and the code will be virtually identical in both cases.

Jon

p.s. Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ

Comment: Hi, As far as i can see, the write method cannot be made in .NET to create on the fly MPP file

and i can't find example files anywhere

Comment: That's correct, MPXJ [does not support writing MPP files](http://www.mpxj.org/faq.html#write-mpp).